# (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: Store in ........... /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/ReaderList.php on line 50

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3.4, multi-website, multidomain

whenever i am setting additional domains for multi website setup, the additional domains are accessible for 1 day and on the next day i am getting error on magento 2.3.4

```
(Exception): Notice: Undefined index: Store in ........... /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/ReaderList.php on line 50
```

[image: website, store, storeview pointing domains]

have done MAGE_RUN_CODE & MAGE_RUN_TYPE for all,
other than the default website luxeron.in, all other 3 website were working after making changes in virtualhost.conf, htaccess, index.php and gives an error after a day,

there is a theme being used for default website luxeron.in, however now i have changed it back to Luma.
below are the changes done

> .htaccess

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
                    
                    SetEnvIf Host .*deewaligifts.com* MAGE_RUN_CODE=DGUSEN
                    SetEnvIf Host .*deewaligifts.com* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

                    SetEnvIf Host .*decobins.com* MAGE_RUN_CODE=DBUSEN
                    SetEnvIf Host .*decobins.com* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

                    SetEnvIf Host .*niwtn.com* MAGE_RUN_CODE=NIWINEN
                    SetEnvIf Host .*niwtn.com* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

> index.php

```
/**--------------------------------- Multisite Setup -------------**/
        switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
            
            /*-----------------------Default Luxeron.in ------------------**/
            default :
                $mageRunCode = 'LUX';
                $mageRunType = 'website';
            break;
            /*-------------------------------DeewaliGifts ----------------**/
            case 'DeewlaiGifts.com':
                $mageRunCode = 'DGUSEN';
                $mageRunType = 'store';
            break;
            /*------------------------------ Decobins --------------------**/
            case 'decobins.com':
                $mageRunCode = 'DBUSEN';
                $mageRunType = 'store';
            break;
               /*------------------------------ NiwTn --------------------**/
            case 'NiwTn.com':
                $mageRunCode = 'NIWINEN';
                $mageRunType = 'store';
            break;
        }
        
        /**--------------------------------- end of websites --------------**/
        $params = $_SERVER;
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
```

> webuzoVH.conf

```
ServerName deewaligifts.com
ServerAlias www.deewaligifts.com

DocumentRoot /home/nittn/luxeron/pro
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "DGUSEN"
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "Store"

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/apps/php72/var/php72_9000.sock|fcgi://localhost"  
    </If>

#------------------------------#
ServerName decobins.com
ServerAlias www.decobins.com

DocumentRoot /home/nittn/luxeron/pro
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "DBUSEN"
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "Store"


<FilesMatch \.php$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/apps/php72/var/php72_9000.sock|fcgi://localhost"  
    </If>
#-----------------------------#
ServerName niwtn.com
ServerAlias www.niwtn.com
    
DocumentRoot /home/nittn/luxeron/pro
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "NIWINEN"
            SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "Store"
    
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/local/apps/php72/var/php72_9000.sock|fcgi://localhost"  
    </If>
```